# Is it a weakness of Henkin's completeness proof that consistency is undecidable?

Tags: logic

An important step in Henkin's proof of the completeness of first-order logic is the construction of maximally consistent sets of sentences from the original set $\Gamma$. In order to do this, he describes a series of steps whereby we add the next (from an arbitrary numbering) sentence that is consistent with the set we have accumulated thus far ($\Gamma_{0i}$), to produce the next set ($\Gamma_{0i+1}$).

What bothers me about this is that there is no decision procedure for determining whether a sentence is consistent with a set of sentences. So are we supposed to consult some oracle to determine whether we can add the next sentence to the set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a real thing. However, I wouldn't call it a *weakness*, just a feature of the topic: non-computable things are more relevant here than they are in many other contexts.

Briefly, here's the situation. Henkin's proof breaks into multiple pieces:

- If $T$ is a complete consistent first-order theory with the witness property (also called the Henkin property), then the term structure $Term(T)$ of $T$ is in fact a model of $T$.
- Every consistent theory $S$ is (possibly after expanding the language appropriately) a subtheory of a theory $T$ which is consistent, complete (with respect to the new language) and has the witness property.

The first step is totally "effective:" we can build a copy of $Term(T)$ computably from $T$ assuming $T$ has the desired hypotheses. However, the second step is *not* effective, and indeed the whole result is not:

> There is a consistent computable theory with no computable model.

For example, this is a consequence of [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). Add a new constant symbol $c$ to the usual language of first-order Peano arithmetic $\mathsf{PA}$, and consider the new theory $$A=\mathsf{PA}\cup\{c>1+...+1\mbox{ ($n$ times)}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ The theory $A$ is satisfiable by compactness, but by Tennenbaum it can have no computable model. *(We can also get a single sentence which has a model but has no computable model with a bit more thought, so the "infinitely many axioms" thing is really superficial here.)

Put another way, the completeness theorem is "classically true but computably false." But (to my mind anyways) non-computable things aren't particularly ontologically mysterious: some things are computable, some things aren't, and the appearance of non-computable objects in reasonably concrete arguments should be construed not as evidence that those arguments are flawed but rather that those objects are less inaccessible than they may at first appear.

If this sort of thing interests you, you should look up [**reverse mathematics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics): this is basically the study of how much "computational power" different theorems of mathematics have. From the perspective of reverse mathematics, the completeness theorem sits at the same level as (for example) the theorem that $[0,1]$ is compact or the theorem that every infinite binary tree has an infinite path.

Comment: By "indeed the whole result is not [effective]", do you mean to point out that if Henkin's proof could effectively produce a model for every consistent theory, then it would contradict Tenenbaum's theorem?

Comment: If we have no effective procedure for determining consistency of sets of first-order statements, then what does it mean to assert that they "are" or "are not" consistent?

I guess the idea is that one could enumerate all possible proofs involving those statements. And though one could never verify that none of them led to a contradiction, it makes sense to assert that none of them lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @LyleK "If we have no effective procedure for determining consistency of sets of first-order statements, then what does it mean to assert that they "are" or "are not" consistent?" You're implicitly assuming there that only "computably witnessable" mathematics is valid. While that's certainly a stance one can take it's not the usual one (to put it mildly). Moreover this is more common than you may think: "every commutative ring which is not a field has a nontrivial proper ideal" is a standard theorem of abstract algebra, but isn't computably true - are you equally skeptical of that theorem now?

Comment: (That is, a computable commutative ring which is not a field need not have a computable nontrivial proper ideal.) If you want to take a "computable-stuff-only" stance that's something you can indeed do, but you need to $(i)$ adopt it consistently throughout mathematics and $(ii)$ recognize that that's not the standard perspective. That said, if you are interested in this one useful keyword is "constructivism" - see e.g. [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/varieties-of-constructive-mathematics/russian-constructive-mathematics/070A460B0528EC7D95B85A7EFCD48DD0), especially chapter 3.

Comment: I am interested in intuitionistic/constructive logic, but I'm sure I believe lots of things that were proved non-constructively. What I need to remember in this case is that since I have already accepted the premise in the proof that $\Gamma$ is consistent, it shouldn't be hard to accept that $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$ is either consistent or inconsistent, without needing to know which. I already noticed that the proof makes use of LEM, and that didn't bother me. If I could follow a formal proof like [this one](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Completeness-paper.pdf), it might help me.